# Looping through large array without freezing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's say I have an array of 10000 random integers. I want to while loop through it and add each number to a `ul`. The thing is, if I do something like this:

```js
const myArray = [/* 10000 totally random integers! */];
let pos = 0;
while (pos < myArray.length) {
  document.getElementById("unorderedList").innerHTML += `<li>${pos}</li>`;
  pos++;
}
console.log("done!");
```

It freezes the whole window until it finishes, then it logs everything. How can I make it so the loop adds the number *every iteration* until it finishes instead of finishing the loop *then* printing everything?
Note: this hypothetical function also needs to interact with a `Window` created with `window.open`, so I don't think I can use workers since that interacts with the DOM.

Comment: adding to `.innerHTML` every iteration is the slowest way to do this. build up a string and add it once - it'll take 4ms, or use a document fragment - by the way, the content of `myArray` is completely unused in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

It is due to the browser being busy updating the DOM in each iteration of the loop, and the rendering process is blocking the script execution.

## Solution

You can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to break the loop into smaller chunks, which allows the browser to handle rendering between each chunk.

```
const myArray = [/* 10000 totally random integers! */];
let pos = 0;
const chunkSize = 50; // adjust it according to your myArray size
const ul = document.getElementById("unorderedList");

function processArrayChunk() {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < chunkSize && pos < myArray.length; i++, pos++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = myArray[pos];
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  }

  ul.appendChild(fragment);

  if (pos < myArray.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(processArrayChunk);
  } else {
    console.log("done!");
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(processArrayChunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to split your code into batches:

Creating each of 10,000 `<li>${pos}</li>` snippet, and combining them, and only then adding to the `<ul>` takes 4 milliseconds

```js
console.time('init');
const array = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)); 
console.timeEnd('init');
console.time('fill');
document.getElementById('unorderedList').innerHTML += array.map((v, pos) => `<li>${pos}</li>`).join('');
console.timeEnd('fill');
```

```html
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
```

or, using fragment

```js
console.time('init');
const array = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)); 
console.timeEnd('init');
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
console.time('fill');
array.forEach((v, pos) => frag.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(pos)));
document.getElementById('unorderedList').append(frag);
console.timeEnd('fill');
```

```html
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create 10000 DOM elements at once thus blocking the UI. You should implement virtual scrolling (here some very simple one). It even scrolls better.

```js
const arr = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.random());

unorderedList.style.height = (arr.length * 32) + 'px';

drawItems();

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', drawItems);

function drawItems(){
debugger;
  const pos = wrapper.scrollTop;
  const from = pos / 32 | 0;
  const to = from + wrapper.offsetHeight / 32 | 0 + 1;
  unorderedList.innerHTML = arr.slice(from, to).map((item, idx) => `<li>${from + idx + 1}: ${item}</li>`).join('');
  let top = -32;
  [...unorderedList.children].forEach((li, idx) => li.style.top = `${top += 32}px`);
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li{
 position:absolute;
 height:32px;
 line-hieght:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame`.

> `requestAnimationFrame` is a JavaScript method used for smooth and
> efficient animations on the web.
>
> It schedules a provided function to run before the next repaint,
> ensuring optimal performance by syncing with the browser's rendering
> cycle.
>
> Unlike alternatives like `setTimeout`, it adapts to the screen refresh
> rate, resulting in visually smoother animations and better resource
> utilization.

It's commonly used in animation loops for updating positions and redrawing scenes.

I add sample code below.

```js
const myArray = new Array(10000).fill(0).map((_, index) => index);
const batchSize = 30; //you can control speed by this variable
let pos = 0;
const unorderedList = document.getElementById("unorderedList");

const updateDOM = () => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  while (pos < myArray.length && fragment.children.length < batchSize) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = myArray[pos++];
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  }

  unorderedList.appendChild(fragment);

  pos < myArray.length ? requestAnimationFrame(updateDOM) : stop();
};

const start = () => requestAnimationFrame(updateDOM);
const stop = () => console.log("done!");

start();
```

```html
<div id="unorderedList"></div>
```

Comment: All well and good ... 30 per "batch" takes 5.5 seconds ... 10000 per batch takes under 9ms ... no need for batches at all :p